# Error on installing rCharts in R 3.1.1 (Windows)

Tags: r, rcharts

Is there a build of rCharts available for R 3.1.1?

I tried 2 methods and both failed:

Method 1:

```
devtools::install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')
Downloading github repo ramnathv/rCharts@master
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

Method 2: (Manually downloading the package and running install.packages )

```
install.packages("~/R/win-library/rCharts-master.zip", repos = NULL)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘~/R/win-library/rCharts-master.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Edit: I tried:

```
library(downloader)
download("https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/archive/master.tar.gz", "rCharts.tar.gz")
install.packages("rCharts.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

And it works now! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried install_github on another R package? Sounds like a network permissions issue.

Comment: You might also need to specify `type="source"` for installing from source.

Comment: Works for me. I vote on @Stedy's comment that it's a network issue.

Comment: With method 2, use `devtools::install_local` instead of `install.packages`.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. Please change your edits to a separate answer so that others can find it more easily.