# R Installing rCharts on R 3.4.2 x64

Tags: r, installation, rcharts

I had a little bit of trouble installing rCharts for R version 3.2.1. I have referenced a question that addresses an earlier version of R, but the solution did not work for me exactly. [[Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517961/error-on-installing-rcharts-in-r-3-1-1-windows)

It would appear that there wasn't a rCharts package for R that can be installed using the `install.packages()` command

Updated for 3.2.2 x64

Updated for 3.4.2 x64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I hope my way helps.

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("Rcpp")
library(devtools)
library(Rcpp)
install_github('ramnathv/rCharts', force= TRUE)
```

I have tested this method on a clean install of R 3.4.2 x64.

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]

> install.packages("devtools")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/frank/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 443924 bytes (433 KB)
downloaded 433 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEJRBVY\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/frank/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4353971 bytes (4.2 MB)
downloaded 4.2 MB

package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEJRBVY\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
> library(Rcpp)
> install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')
Skipping install of 'rCharts' from a github remote, the SHA1 (479a4f98) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
> install.packages("devtools")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> library(devtools)
> library(Rcpp)
> install_github('ramnathv/rCharts', force= TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo ramnathv/rCharts@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ramnathv/rCharts/zipball/master

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("devtools")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/frank/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 443924 bytes (433 KB)
downloaded 433 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiSWkVr\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
> library(Rcpp)
> install_github('ramnathv/rCharts', force= TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo ramnathv/rCharts@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ramnathv/rCharts/zipball/master
Installing rCharts
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/frank/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiSWkVr/devtools3ff09fd3b8/ramnathv-rCharts-479a4f9"  \
  --library="C:/Users/frank/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'rCharts' ...
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (rCharts)
```

Answer (score 3):

The first answer did not work for me. But try this one:

Download the package from https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts as zip file and expand it to

```
"C:\rchartsdownload"
```

Then, install the following packages:

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("RJSONIO")
library(devtools)
library(Rcpp)
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
```

and finally:

```
install.packages("C:/rchartsdownload", repos = NULL, type="source")
```